# What is the difference between equal and eql in Chai Library

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I have a question regarding Chai library for unit tests. I noticed a statement saying:

- [`equal`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal): Asserts that the target is **strictly** (`===`) equal to the given value.
- [`eql`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql): Asserts that the target is **deeply** equal to value.

I'm confused about what the difference is between **strictly** and **deeply**.

Answer (score 48):

**Strictly equal** (or `===`) means that your are comparing **exactly the same** object to itself:

```
var myObj = {
   testProperty: 'testValue'
};
var anotherReference = myObj;

expect(myObj).to.equal(anotherReference); // The same object, only referenced by another variable
expect(myObj).to.not.equal({testProperty: 'testValue'}); // Even though it has the same property and value, it is not exactly the same object
```

**Deeply Equal** on the other hand means that every **property** of the compared objects (and possible deep linked objects) have the same value. So:

```
var myObject = {
    testProperty: 'testValue',
    deepObj: {
        deepTestProperty: 'deepTestValue'
    }
}
var anotherObject = {
    testProperty: 'testValue',
    deepObj: {
        deepTestProperty: 'deepTestValue'
    }
}
var myOtherReference = myObject;

expect(myObject).to.eql(anotherObject); // is true as all properties are the same, even the inner object (deep) one
expect(myObject).to.eql(myOtherReference) // is still also true for the same reason
```

Comment: To be honest this is a horrific convention. I think only `equal` and `deepEqual` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

here

1. equal is ===
   checks if both object references or points to the exact same or identical object.

   var obj = {
   k1: 'v1'
   };

   var obj1 = obj
   var obj2 = obj
   here obj1 === obj2 (true)
   and obj1 == obj2 (true)

eql: Asserts that the target is deeply equal to value.
number 2 ie. eql checks if both objects have the same value. (they could be different objects with the same values )

```
var obj1 = {
   k1: 'v1'
}

var obj2 = {
   k1: 'v1'
};
```

There are a few plugins that help you in terms of the above condition where you can simply use _.isEqual to check the object values:

UnderScore
Lodash
isDeepStrictEqual(object1, object2) Node
eg console.log(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)); // true